# How to repeat an html element n number of times using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print an element, in my case an hr tag some number of times according to the length of a word. This code is for a hangman game I'm trying to recreate. I have looked up similar questions and its not quite what I'm lookin for.

This is my javascript code so far.

```
var words = ['Quaffle', 'Bludger', 'Golden Snitch', 'Time-Turner', 
'Pensieve', 'Mirror of Erised'];

function getRandomWord(){
   var randomIndex = words[Math.floor(Math.random()* words.length)]; 
   alert(randomIndex);
}

function printDashes(){
   var dashes = document.getElementById("dash")
}

getRandomWord()
printDashes()
```

I'm not sure what to add after retrieving the element. Can someone guide me on how to go about this?

Comment: What is the output looks like:

Comment: You would have to get the length of the string from your randomly selected item, then loop over the length and print out your lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your word is in some variable named `myWord`.
Get the length of the word by doing:

```
var myWordLen = myWord.length;
```

Then you can create HTML elements using Javascript `createElement` method and appending child elements, information etc as needed. But since you want as many elements as the length of a word, use a loop. Eg:

```
for(var i=0; i < myWordLen; i++)
{
    var tr1 = document.createElement("hr");
    var someEle = document.getElementById("someID");
    someEle.appendChild(tr1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. I have specific css for the hr element. How will I link that with the create element?

Comment: If you have CSS for some class (like `.foo {color:red}` ), all you need to do is add that that class `foo` while creating the new `hr` element by doing:  `tr1.className += " foo";`

Comment: So should I be putting this in my getRandomWord() function?

Comment: I don't know that, depends on your code logic. All I have shown is a generic way to create elements, add class to them and append them to another element as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create div's so you can enter letters when the user inputs a character. I've attached an example below.

**UPDATE: Added example code to update the dashes with letters based on word**

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('container');
var guess = document.getElementById('guess');
var word = "Hello";

// draw empty dashes
var drawDashes = function(numberOfDashes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDashes; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.classList = 'dash';
    
    // we draw an empty character inside so that the element
    // doesn't adjust height when we update the dash later with a 
    // letter inside
    el.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';

    elem.appendChild(el);
  }
}

// update dash with a letter based on index
var updateDash = function(index, letter) {
  elem.children[index].innerHTML = letter;
}

guess.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {

  // split the word up into characters
  var splitWord = word.split('');
   
  // check to see if the letter entered matches any of the
  // words characters
  for (var i = 0; i < splitWord.length; i++ ) {
  
    // it is important we convert them to lowercase or 
    // else we might get a mismatch because of case-sensitivity
    if (evt.key.toLowerCase() === splitWord[i].toLowerCase()) {
    
      // update dash with letter based on index
      updateDash(i, evt.key.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
  
  // clear out the value
  this.value = '';
});

drawDashes(word.length);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.dash {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#guess {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0; 
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<h4>Type a letter</h4>
<input id="guess" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be helpful.

Comment: How would I go about this code if I want to replace the dashes with the correct letters?

Comment: @Devika.S Added an example in post but please reframe from additional questions on top of an existing question

Answer (score 0):

What about this way?

```
myElement.innerHTML = `<...>`.repeat(words.length)
```